# Can i make one static files that used in all apps?

Tags: django, django-templates, backend

Im using **Django** and i want to make a **static **file that can used in **all** apps templates

this is the **tree** of my project

```
C:.
├───AISystem
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───imgs
│   │   │   ├───myfont
│   │   │   └───result
│   │   └───js
│   └───__pycache__
├───Text2imageApp
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───text2voiceApp
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
└───texttohandwriting
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───templates
    └───__pycache__
```

as you can see i put my css file in the (**../AISystem/static/css/main_style.css**) and i want to use it in other apps templates.

my **setting.py** file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'AISystem\static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**template** file in this dir : (**Text2imageApp/templates/main.html**)

```
{% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IntelliHub</title>
    <link rel="main_style" href="i dont know what to write here">
```

**how i can link main.html with the main_style.css?**

Answer (score 0):

You can write `<link rel="main_style" href="{% static 'css/main_style.css' %}">`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the one static folder for all apps that contains the css, js and images.
To include the static file in your template follow the below steps:-

1. load the static {% load static %} in your template.
2. add the static :-`<link rel="main_style" href="{%static 'css/main_style.css'%}">`